# Regex for finding string after nth occurrence of hyphen

Tags: regex, parsing, extract

I have the multiple rows of strings that look like the following:

```
irm-eap-edp-refined-nonprod
irm-eap-edp-reporting-prod
irm-eap-edp-development-nonprod
```

I need to extract the nonprod or prod string from each, it will always be after the 4th hyphen and the last substring of the entire string.

What's a simple regex for this situation?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the last substring after `-` you can do:

```
.*-(.*)
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/hGVDi5/1)

Comment: Yeah, that's definitely simpler than mine, +1 :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could substitute everything starting with 4 `[^-]+-` chunks with nothing:

```
/^(?:[^-]+-){4}//gm
```

- `^` - start of line anchor
- `[^-]+-` - match on anything but `-` 1 or more times followed by a `-`
- `(?:` ... `)` - non capturing group
- `{4}` - four times

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5VKmhK/1)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you want is `prod` or `nonprod` after a hyphen, and at the end of a string, so:

```
-(prod|nonprod)$
```

This has the benefit of the prod/nonprod being in the capture group.